# EAS react-native build has instances of EXUpdatesControllerRegistry without expo-updates library

Tags: react-native, expo, app-store, eas

I'm currently building an iOS app with React Native (managed by Expo). I use EAS (Expo Application Services) to create a production build for the Apple App Store.

However, on each app review, the app gets rejected with the following reason -

`Thank you for your response. We appreciate your feedback, however, your app is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. To comply with Guideline 2.3.1 and 2.5.2, it would be appropriate to remove any and all remote code importing or hot updating support from your app, such as your app’s ExpoKit hot updating support and the EXUpdatesControllerRegistry support class.`

I do not use `expo-updates`. I don't have `expo-updates` in my `package.json` and while building it on EAS, I don't have any instances of `Expo` (or `EXUpdates*`) during the "Install Pods" phase of the build process.

Are there any changes (in the build process) that I need to do/make or any additional libraries that I need to remove so that my app passes the App Store review?

Versions -

```
expo - 47.0.0
```

I took a look at - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1865#issuecomment-486757797
and issued a similar response to the App Store, however, it did not work. I've made sure that OTA updates have been removed (no `expo-updates` in the `package.json`)